# Formatting a decimal as currency with plus and minus signs in c#

Tags: c#

Is there a way to format a decimal so that it appears as a currency with both + or - signs?

For example:

+$5.00 (plus sign for greater than zero)
$0.00 (no sign for zero)
-$5.00 (minus sign for less than zero)

The following does what I want but not sure how to incorporate currency:

```
var formattedprice = $"{price:+0;-#}"
```

I would typically use C0 for currency or N0 for number.

Comment: If this is for an international application, keep in mind that not all currency symbols appear in front of the numeric value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pos = 5m;
        var zero = 0m;
        var neg = -5m;

        var format = "+$0.00;-$0.00;$0.00";

        Console.WriteLine(pos.ToString(format));
        Console.WriteLine(zero.ToString(format));
        Console.WriteLine(neg.ToString(format));
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
+$5,00
$0,00
-$5,00
```

and as per @xxbbcc's comment, currency symbol location depends on locale so you'll have to change the format in accordance.

Comment: Not just the currency symbol but the negative formatting - as a simple example, this is ok but if you want to handle international formatting, you need to handle possible variations of how negative numbers are shown (minus sign, parenthesis, etc.) When you use a custom format string, none of those are handled for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#SectionSeparator

Comment: @xxbbcc, that's for sure, yet as far as I understood TS' issue, the problem was with customizing the format, otherwise it is much easier to adhere to system default provided by C2. I am pretty sure TS is aware of aforementioned functionality yet there is a need for something non-standard hence the question.

Comment: Sure, I just pointed it out for completeness' sake.